# React How Can I pass Index outsite of map fuction?

Tags: reactjs, function

just working on the carousel. Just trying to disable the button when it ends. disabled={ index === 0 } does not working because out of map scope.
Thank you for the help.

```
<Carousel settings={ settings } ref={ ref }>
    {slides.map((el, index) => (
      <SlideGallery key={ index }>
        <SlideItems style={{ background: el.imgUrl }}>
          <picture><img src={ el.imgUrl } alt=''></img></picture>
          <SlideInner>
            <h3>{el.review}</h3>
            <p></p>
            <p>UserName</p>
          </SlideInner>
        </SlideItems>
      </SlideGallery>
    ))}
  </Carousel>
  <ButtonWrapper>
    <PrevButton onClick={ prevSlide } disabled={ index === 0 }><ChevronLeft/></PrevButton>
    <NextButton onClick={ nextSlide }><ChevronRigt/></NextButton>
  </ButtonWrapper>
```

Comment: You need to store the **current** slide index in state, and use that to enable/disable the buttons

Comment: your Carousel opening tag has a wrong spelling.